# Чому "педагог математики" не правильно?

Tags: терміни, правопис

Чому не можна сказати "педагог математики"? Шукала на просторах інтернету, але не знайшла відповідного правила.

Comment: Вчитель/викладач — це той, хто має вчити/викладати. Але на практиці сталося так, що вчитель часто виконує дві ролі: **вчити/викладати** і **виховувати**. Коли кажуть «педагог» (гр. παιδαγωγική — мистецтво виховання) на вчителя/викладача, то зазвичай підкреслюється його роль як вихователя або ж його здатність до передачі знань загалом (а не його роль чи здатність надавати знання з конкретного предмету). Тому слово «педагог» з назвами конкретних дисциплін несумісне. Це як «вихователь… з фізики» (або ж «майстерний у передаванні знань у цілому… з фізики»).

Answer (score 2):

На сайті [Уроки державної мови](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/209.htm) міститься така відповідь на Ваше запитання:

> Учитель — педагог
>
> **Чи можна вчителя математики назвати педагогом математики?**
>
> Педагог — це фахівець, що викладає якийсь предмет, проводить виховну роботу в навчальному закладі. Тому, коли йдеться про рід занять, іменники педагог і вчитель виступають як синоніми. Але якщо вислови вчитель математики, вчитель фізики, вчитель історії, вчитель української мови, вчитель географії та інші нормативні, то ***словосполучення педагог математики, педагог історії, педагог географії і под.*** ***неприродні й неприйнятні***.